# Hot to get clients location data in Dialogflow CX

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-cx

I am writing an app in dialogflow CX which suggests locations to a user based on position and other data about the user.

The flow for the user requesting a location works by sending dummy coordinates to my python flask using a webhook. The flask sends a location back which gets presented to the user. So far so good.

My current objective is not sending dummy coordinates but using the clients real location.
This is my first time working with dialogflow CX and I've also never used any other Google service like actions on Google or dialogflow ES.

After some research I only found old documentation on how to extract client information using dialogflow ES. Some other documentations claim it is now only possible with actions on Google.

So I tried using dialogflow ES documentations and got rich content working.
Sadly the "old" solution for getting user data using dialogflow ES helpers did not work for me or I simply used them wrong. Any help, solution or clarification on how to solve this problem or if it is even possible to do this in dialogflow CX is greatly appreciated for I am getting more confused by the documentation than actual help!

Answer (score 0):

And what device is your user in to get that info?

I asume you could ask the customer for his location as well.

I recommend you to check the ES connector of Voximplant, that would allow to have that flow very easily over chat or voicecall as well.

You can pass any metadata to the webhook and provide the flutter response in the chat.

I mean, instead of using the DF fulfillment, you use Voximplant that is easier to work with.

Here a [tutorial to connect DF CX to Telephony](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QCN0IXVpQ8&list=PLdnlYPuoAQbcv7qkvnVG0Kkd30SJDjzIC) and
[How to have a custom channel to be responded by DF bot](https://voximplant.com/kit/docs/Channels/Custom).

Let me know if you have questions about this.